# MongoDB Loadbalancer is not working as execpted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-java-driver

I have multiple mongos in below URI.
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

mongodb://username:password@host123:40000,host124:40000,host124:40000/admin?ssl=true

We are created a MongoClient and try to read some value from collection, then prints

```
System.out.println("Server Address: " + mongoClient.getAddress());
System.out.println("Connection Point: " + mongoClient.getConnectPoint());
```

It always returning **host123**, its not working as round robin. Any changes required in connection URI?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB will use `hostN` as a fall over for redundancy, if you want to deploy load balancing you'll have to deploy your own load balancer to the mix.

Comment: oh okay, above connection string will not help us for load balancer?

I heard from one of the MongoDB vendor, above connection string act as load balancer URI,its not true?

Comment: What do you mean by load balancing? What setup do you have?